# Video in between Head and Footer

Tags: html, css, video

I need some help with my messy code (excuse me for having lot of text in my native language). I need to fit the IFRAME in between head and footer of the site, so it will look the same on every monitor (resolution).
Thanks!

```css
body {
margin: 0;
background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #292c33, #a0b2d0, #dee9f6, #a0b2d0, #292c33);
}
p{
    color: #272727;
    text-align: left;
    display: block;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    padding-left: 14px;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-decoration: none;
    
    //  nadefinování písma na stránce   
}


.nav{
    background-color: #eaeaea;
    overflow: hidden;
  
}

.nav a{
    float: left;
    display: block;
    color: #272727;         //  barva fontu
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 100%;
    border-bottom: 3px solid transparent;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    height: 30px;
}
.nav a:hover{
    border-bottom: 3px solid #310a0b;
}
.nav a.active{
    border-bottom: 3px solid #b50c0f;
}



.fotka{
    display: block;
    float: right;
    width: 5%;
    height: 5%;
    margin: 12px;                    
    }
footer{
    padding: 1px;
    background-color: #eaeaea;
    color: #272727;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
 
}

.zvideo{
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    padding-top: 0%;
   
    
  
   
    
                                                                          
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="cs">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    
    <link rel='icon' href='favicon.ico?' type='image/x-icon'/>
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
            
    <title>Hlavní stránka</title> 
</head>
    <body>
        <div class="nav">
            <a class="active" href="index.html">Domů</a>
            <a href="Druha.html">Zaklínač</a>          
            <a href="Treti.html">Hry</a>
            <a href="Ctvrta.html">Knížky</a>

            <img class="fotka" alt="logo stránky" src="logo.png">

        </div>
<!--NÁSLEDUJE DIV IFRAMU-->
       <div class="zvideo">
            <iframe class="zvideo" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/hquuwfa3FCo?autoplay=1&mute=1" width="1152px" height="648px" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay"></iframe>
       </div>
       
       <footer>
           <p>Autor: Jan Michalisko</p>
           <p>Můj email: hachikolp@gmail.com</p>       <!--mailto: mi přišel velmi barbarský, takže jsem tam nechal jenom paragraf-->
       </footer>

   </body>
</html>
```

I hope that you will be able to identify what is footer, head etc., i am really not a good at coding yet, lol. Thank you for help!

Comment: please specify `looking the same on every monitor`. That is impossible as every monitor has a different pixel size as well as screen ratios.

Comment: Oh, I mean that it will be in the center of the screen, I tried to set it with margin-left and margin-right, looked fine on my 1920x1080 monitor, but when i put it on my 1600x900 notebook, the video wasn't centered at all.
I just want it to be in the center of the screen somehow!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the comments, you just trying to `center` an `iframe`. The `I` in `iframe` stands for `inline`. So the correct name for the `<iframe>` tag is: `inline frame`. As the name indictaes, it is not a `block level element` but an `inline element`. As such it can not be centered by using `margin: 0 auto;` by default. So you need to add `display: block;` first, in order to change the `iframe` into a `block level element`.

```css
iframe {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<iframe src="">Just a Test</iframe>
```

Comment: Yes! This is what I wanted, thank you for all the informations!